# Add annotation with a Quarkus extension

Tags: quarkus

Here is what I like to achieve.

My Quarkus app is using a homemade Quarkus extension that is securing my API endpoints with a custom annotation:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuthorizationSecured {
    @Nonbinding String[] permissions() default{};
}
```

I want this custom annotation to automatically annotate my endpoints with this openapi annotation:

```java
// org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement
@SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt")
```

So that in swagger-ui, I can have the [padlock icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDv7.png) displayed and [specify my token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyj36.png) when clicking on the icon.

Any idea?

EDIT:

I tried @Ladicek suggestion, here is my processor:

```java
class AuthorizeProcessor {

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem("authorize");
    }

    @BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem registerConfigValidator() {
        // some stuff here...
    }

    @BuildStep
    AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem transform() {
        return new AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem(new AnnotationsTransformer() {

            public boolean appliesTo(org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.Kind kind) {
                return kind == AnnotationTarget.Kind.METHOD;
            }

            public void transform(TransformationContext context) {
                if (context.getTarget().asMethod().hasAnnotation(DotName.createSimple("com.software.company.AuthorizationSecured"))) {
                    context.transform().add(DotName.createSimple("org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement"), AnnotationValue.createStringValue("name", "jwt")).done();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @BuildStep
    void registerAuthorizeFilter(
            BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeanProducer,
            BuildProducer<AdditionalIndexedClassesBuildItem> additionalIndexedClassesProducer,
            BuildProducer<ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem> resteasyJaxrsProviderProducer) {
        // some stuff here...
    }
}
```

The annotation transformer seems to do its job, I have printed some stuff in the console:

```
************* Found method name = secured
************* annotations before > [@GET, @Path(value = "/secured"), @Produces(value = ["text/plain"]), @AuthorizationSecured]
************* annotations after > [@GET, @Path(value = "/secured"), @Produces(value = ["text/plain"]), @AuthorizationSecured, @org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt")]
```

But actually, I don't see any effect at runtime on the app that is using the extension. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your extension can define a build step that produces the `AnnotationTransformationBuildItem`. The annotation transformation can inspect given annotation targets and add the interceptor binding annotation if required.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I didn't really understand what you mean and I couldn't find any `AnnotationTransformationBuildItem`. Could you give me more details please?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it from memory. The right name is `AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem`.  Specifically the `io.quarkus.arc.deployment.AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem` one. See for example https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-integration#annotations_transformer_build_item

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ladicek, I'll give it a try. Just to clarify, my goal is not to override an annotation that exists on a bean class, it is to automatically add an annotation on the top of another one. So instead of having to declare `@AuthorizationSecured + @SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt")` on every endpoint I want to secure, I want to declare only `@AuthorizationSecured` and `@SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt")` will apply automatically. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Sure, annotation transformer should be able to do that just fine. Note that the transformed annotations are not written physically to the class, it's an overlay only seen by the CDI container -- but you want to add an interceptor binding, so that's exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok, did you take a look at my edited post? The annotation transformer does its job, but I don't see any effect at runtime.

Comment: Ouch, why exactly did I think the annotation you're adding is an interceptor binding? :scratches-head: ... Okay, yea, what you're doing is fine, except as I said -- the added annotation will only be seen by the CDI container. Sorry, my advice is totally useless. I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. I will try a workaround, I can use the extension to scan all methods annotated with `@AuthorizationSecured` and if such a method doesn't have `@SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt")`, the extension will throw an exception. In my use case those 2 annotations need to be together. It's not the best solution but it will do the job.

Comment: @Ladicek, I think your can write an answer mentionning `AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem` and I'll accept it as a answer as it was basically what I was looking for. Thank you.